# Clearing edit text data

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have certain edit text fields. I save the data entered in these fields to my database, which opens in another activity.

But I have a problem when I navigate back to the first activity (Using the back button on the hardware of the emulator) to add next record, the edit field data is retained.

I tried `onPause()` and `myEditText.setText("")` also. But the dat simple clears off the edit fields but as soon as I click the fields to enter data again the previous data reappears.

I also tried using `finish()` and everything works except I have to go through all the activities again to enter the data.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one also.

```
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    String uid=editText1.getText().toString();
                    String pwd=editText2.getText().toString();
                  editText1.setText("");
                    editText2.setText("");
                        }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
editText.getText().clear();
```

Comment: not working :( It does get cleared at button click but as soon as I click the fields again the previous values reappear.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure that I understood you clearly. You enter text in EditText boxes. Then press a button which takes you to a new activity. But, when you go back to the old activity the text in the EditText boxes doesn't get clear. Try to do `editText.setText("");` when you click the button. I know you said that you tried it, but did you try it inside the function which listens for the button click?

```
public EditText editText;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // As soon as button is clicked, set is as empty
    editText.setText("");
}
```

Try and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Shobhit Puri Thanx for your time. Actually I did try doing what you suggested, but in vain. It does get cleared at button click but as soon as I click the fields again the previous values reappear.

Comment: Is there any way I can use something that works like finish( ) but where I dont actually have go back to the main screen to start my activity again?

Comment: You know it will be helpful if you post the Activity class code, which is creating this issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this library to clear text by a clear icon
[image]

http://droidparts.org/widgets.html#clearableedittext

Answer (score 0):

after onclick of any action do below step

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.yoursXmlId)).setText("");
```

or else

write this in XML file

EditText

```
android:hint="Enter Name" />
```

i did this way.try

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
myEditText.setText(null);
```